# Using abstract base classes to specify an interface enforcing input and return types

Tags: python, abstract-class

I want to write an abstract base class that should enforce that its derived classes implement one method with specific parameters and specific returns.

However, since in Python you specify neither the return type nor the argument types in the method's signature, how can I enforce such an interface?

For example:

```
class BaseClass(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def __call__(self, image, labels=None):
        pass
```

I want derived classes to have to implement the `__call__()` method such that it accepts as arguments a 3D Numpy array (`image`) and, optionally, a 2D Numpy array (`labels`), and that it returns a 3D Numpy array (the transformed image) and, once again optionally, a 2D Numpy array (the transformed labels).

How can I enforce, for example, that the `__call__()` method in a derived class must return exactly that (a 3D Numpy array and, optionally, a 2D Numpy array)?

Comment: You can't do that statically, you can fail at runtime using metaclass.

Comment: @MatanShahar Thank you! Could you elaborate? Specifically, what exactly does "using metaclass" mean?